# Reduce repetitive HTML output in my code

Tags: php

How can I reduce the following code?

```html
<img src='http://x1<?php echo $ranx ; ?>.ddff.com/t/<?php echo $cutstr ; ?>/1_<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>.jpg'>
<img src='http://x1<?php echo $ranx ; ?>.ddff.com/t/<?php echo $cutstr ; ?>/2_<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>.jpg'>
<img src='http://x1<?php echo $ranx ; ?>.ddff.com/t/<?php echo $cutstr ; ?>/3_<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>.jpg'>
<img src='http://x1<?php echo $ranx ; ?>.ddff.com/t/<?php echo $cutstr ; ?>/4_<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>.jpg'>
<img src='http://x1<?php echo $ranx ; ?>.ddff.com/t/<?php echo $cutstr ; ?>/5_<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>.jpg'>
<img src='http://x1<?php echo $ranx ; ?>.ddff.com/t/<?php echo $cutstr ; ?>/6_<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>.jpg'>
<img src='http://x1<?php echo $ranx ; ?>.ddff.com/t/<?php echo $cutstr ; ?>/7_<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>.jpg'>
<img src='http://x1<?php echo $ranx ; ?>.ddff.com/t/<?php echo $cutstr ; ?>/8_<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>.jpg'>
<img src='http://x1<?php echo $ranx ; ?>.ddff.com/t/<?php echo $cutstr ; ?>/9_<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>.jpg'>
<img src='http://x1<?php echo $ranx ; ?>.ddff.com/t/<?php echo $cutstr ; ?>/10_<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>.jpg'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but if you are hardcoding this, you can do a loop for nicer code:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { ?>
    <img src='http://x1<?php echo $ranx ; ?>.ddff.com/t/<?php echo $cutstr ; ?>/<?php echo $i; ?>_<?php echo $matches[1]; ?>.jpg'>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your code just reach 9 times looping add `<=` before 10 to make it 10 times.

Comment: Nah..now it is perfect!